# QgsAttributeDialog in PyQGIS Standalone Application

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am trying to implement a desktop application with PyQGIS 3, I have not been able to program a layer info using the attribute dialog that the QGIS API.

This is part of the code that I use:

```
def info(self):
    self.vlayer = QgsVectorLayer('provincias.shp', "Provincias", "ogr")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.vlayer)
    layer = self.vlayer
    features = layer.getFeatures()
    feature_list = list(f for f in features)
    feat = feature_list[0]
    attribute_dialog = QgsAttributeDialog(layer, feat, True)
    attribute_dialog.show()
```

shows the following error:

```
Municipio Failed to create widget with type 'TextEdit',
Provincia Failed to create widget with type 'TextEdit'
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried to find a solution to this problem. But every time I tried to run this code in standalone pyqgis application, it crashed on line `attribute_dialog = QgsAttributeDialog(layer, feat, True)`

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, you know of some documentation on best practices to make a desktop application using pyqgis 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to initialize the default widgets from [`QgisGui.editorWidgetRegistry`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsGui.html#qgis.gui.QgsGui.editorWidgetRegistry). There is also parent missing from your `QgsAttributeDialog` constructor.

Here is a sample code:

```python
QgsGui.editorWidgetRegistry().initEditors()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
f = layer.getFeature(1)
# layer.startEditing() # to edit manually
dialog = QgsAttributeDialog(layer, f, False, iface.mainWindow(), True)
dialog.exec()
```